# Using EROs for proof of the fact that all subspaces of $R^2$ are lines through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having some difficulties in understanding the method in which my lecture notes has gone about proving a fact:

[image: Proof in question]

Above is the proof in question. I do not quite understand the second part of the proof, for the case where $U \neq Span(u)$. My concern is in the connection between the matrix representation and the points (a,b), (c,d) in the proof, as well as the connection between the RREF's (1,e), (0,1) and the points we started with.

Comment: I don't know what is the context for this example though, it seems to me that this set of notes is complicating things for a otherwise very simple problem.

Comment: This does indeed present a very convoluted view of basic linear algebra.

Comment: @Servaes I have always had a sneaking feeling that my lecture notes overcomplicate things (this is first year undergrad linear algebra). Out of curiosity what would be a much shorter way to prove this?

Comment: It depends very much on what has been introduced so far. The fact that the proof is so horrible does not mean that there must be a simpler proof at this point in the notes. It might just not be a good example to introduce at this point.

Comment: @Servaes At this point in the notes only RREF for solving linear equations, and the basic concepts of a vector space has been introduced.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an alternative proof. Though at some point soon you should get a definition of dimension, and a proof of the fact that any two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, which makes this much, much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing elementary row operations on the rows of a matrix yields a matrix whose rows are *linear combinations* of the rows of the original matrix. In particular, the rows of the reduced row echelon form of $\tbinom{a\ b}{c\ d}$are linear combinations of the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

**EDIT:** Here's an alternative proof. It's more geometric (perhaps even visual) in nature, but of course everything can be made rigorous, which is a nice exercise.

---

Let $V:=\Bbb{R}^2$ and let $U\subset V$ be a nontrivial subspace. Then there exists a nonzero $u_1\in U$, and
$$U_1:=\operatorname{Span}(u_1)=\{\lambda u_1:\ \lambda\in\Bbb{R}\}\subset U.$$

Note that $U_1$ is a line through the origin. This shows that:

> If a nonzero vector is contained in $U$, then the line through the origin and that vector is contained in $U$.

Now if there exists $u_2\in U\backslash U_1$, then we can translate the line $U_1$ over the vector $u_2$ to get
$$u_2+U_1:=\{u_2+\lambda u_1:\ \lambda\in\Bbb{R}\}\subset U.$$
Because $u_2$ is not on the line $U_1$, this is a line *not* passing through the origin, parallel to $U_1$. Apart from $U_1$ every line through the origin intersects this line at some point, so by the above, every line through the origin apart from $U_1$ is contained in $U$. And we already saw that $U_1$ is contained in $U$, so $U=V$. So either $U=U_1$ is a line, or $U=V$.

It should be clear that every line through the origin is a subspace; for a given line $L$, take a nonzero point $\ell\in L$. Then $L=\operatorname{Span}(\ell)$.